# Save input value while field is disabled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How do you save an input value, with input field disabled, although you have specified a value?

The value for `@vat_rate` is not being saved:

```
<%= f.text_field :vat, value: @vat_rate, disabled: true %>
```

If disabled is set to false, then the value gets saved to the `:vat` column. Why?

A company is registered for vat at 20% so they are not allowed to change it without approval. On their invoice form, the 20% is displayed and cant be edited. That's how I want it. I want the field to be disabled while making the 20% visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just going to complete @Vasfed's answer: disabled fields are **not** sent to the browser. You could use a hidden field, but please don't (again, see @Vasfed's answer).

To store a value in the session in Rails, you can just set it to `session[:key] = 20`, but it might not be the best idea: you could just re-compute it, or re-fetch it from the DB when you need it.

Comment: I still want to display the value. I can have the model take care of any "manually" changes before saving data.

Comment: @Sylar keep the field disabled to display it, and in your controller, fetch it from your database. That way, it'll be safe, and your users won't be able to tamper it.

Comment: No problem :). You can accept the answer if that worked for you.

Comment: I have to wait 2mins ;)

Answer (score 1):

Do not trust data from the clientside, user may alter your page and gain something from setting other values.

You can for example pass value in session, or via some other way - calculate/fetch it again in create/update action.

Comment: Thanks but how to? Sorry I'm still a noob-ish.

Comment: @Sylar `session[:something] = 123`, but better calculate/fetch it again just before saving